# Running apache website on 2nd IP (FreeBSD/Apache22)

Tags: apache, http, https, freebsd, cloudflare

I've done this before but for some reason can't figure it out this time. I'm running FreeBSD 9.2 64-bit with Apache 2.2. I run a game server and my goal is to run the website through Cloudflare on a new IP address I just ordered due to GET and slowloris attacks.

I will use 1.1.1.1 for my first IP in this question and 1.1.1.2 for my second one (the one I want to run the website under).

I've setup what I think to be the necessary things to do so, but can't make the website load at all. Below is my Listen directive in the httpd.conf file:

```
Listen 1.1.1.2:80
```

That was the first thing I tried, but it didn't work so I moved on. This is the httpd-ssl.conf file:

```
Listen 443

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName domain.com
Redirect / https://domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
#   General setup for the virtual host
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/www/apache22/data"
ServerName domain.com:443
ServerAdmin xx@gmail.com
ErrorLog "/var/log/httpd-error.log"
TransferLog "/var/log/httpd-access.log"
```

Here's my ifconfig output:

```
bge0: flags=8843<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8009b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,LINKSTATE>
        ether 00:19:b9:fa:27:55
        inet 1.1.1.1 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 1.1.1.255
        inet6 ip:v6:addr:ess%bge0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x1
        inet 1.1.1.2 netmask 0xffffffff broadcast 1.1.1.2
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (1000baseT <full-duplex>)
        status: active
bge1: flags=8802<BROADCAST,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 1500
        options=8009b<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,VLAN_MTU,VLAN_HWTAGGING,VLAN_HWCSUM,LINKSTATE>
        ether 00:19:b9:fa:27:56
        nd6 options=29<PERFORMNUD,IFDISABLED,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
        media: Ethernet autoselect (none)
        status: no carrier
lo0: flags=8049<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING,MULTICAST> metric 0 mtu 16384
        options=600003<RXCSUM,TXCSUM,RXCSUM_IPV6,TXCSUM_IPV6>
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128
        inet6 fe80::1%lo0 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x7
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask 0xff000000
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
pflog0: flags=141<UP,RUNNING,PROMISC> metric 0 mtu 33152
        nd6 options=21<PERFORMNUD,AUTO_LINKLOCAL>
```

I've done reading on several sites but can't seem to figure this issue out, I'd greatly appreciate any help. I do have a KVM over IP incase anything goes wrong during the process.

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.2:80>
```

in your config?  The

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

stanza tells Apache to bind a virtual host to port 80 on every IP address, which you don't want.  Interfaces that already have port 80 bound, such as other running webservers, will fail.  If you have another webserver running on this system, you'll also have to tell them to stay off your IP address; they probably have *:80 binds too.